# Hosting internal S3 Website that's accessible over VPN and is secured with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpn, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I've been looking for a solution to host internal S3 website that's accessible over VPN. Clearly I don't wanna use CLoudFront + WAF to restrict the IP range.

I tried setting up the following,

- Created a VPC Endpoint for S3 services
- Created a static S3 website bucket with bucket policy restricting access only through VPC Endpoints.
- Created a private hosted zone and configured an Alias record set to S3 website address

The above solution exposes HTTP endpoint and I wanna secure it with SSL and I'm looking for options.

Have also been looking to setup reverse proxy infront of S3, but couldn't find a clear implementation reference.

Does the above solution would work? Or I'm missing something big?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't host "internal S3 website" using "static S3 website bucket". The bucket in the website mode will always give you a public (i.e. accessible over internet) url. There are no private urls for website buckets.

Answer (score 0):

The S3 VPC Endpoint is configured via the routing of the VPC. For this reason you will not be able to resolve to it outside of the VPC.

However, you could run a private EC2 instance with a proxy in front to forward traffic to your S3 bucket, then set a resolveable hostname to the EC2 instance itself.

*Additional links*

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-routing